# Facebook Pixel on Flutter Web

Tags: flutter, facebook, dart, facebook-pixel

I have a website made in flutter web
that works very well
I recently decided to insert a facebook tool
the facebook Pixel
I used the code provided by facebook to insert on my website

I edited the index.html file and inserted the tags inside the head

```
<!-- Facebook Pixel Code -->
  <script>
  var ran = false;
    !function(f,b,e,v,n,t,s)
    {if(f.fbq)return;n=f.fbq=function(){n.callMethod?
    n.callMethod.apply(n,arguments):n.queue.push(arguments)};
    if(!f._fbq)f._fbq=n;n.push=n;n.loaded=!0;n.version='2.0';
    n.queue=[];t=b.createElement(e);t.async=!0;
    t.src=v;s=b.getElementsByTagName(e)[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(t,s)}(window,document,'script',
    'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js');

      if (rotated == false) {
    rotated = true;
    fbq('init', '########');
   }


    console.log(fbq);
    fbq('track', 'PageView');



</script>x
  <noscript>
    <img height="1" width="1"
         src="https://www.facebook.com/tr?id=########&ev=PageView
&noscript=1"/>
  </noscript>
  <!-- End Facebook Pixel Code -->
```

Now I'm using an extension (Facebook Pixel Helper) to check if the installation is correct
And receive the following message
“The Facebook pixel activated 2 times on this web page, which can cause errors in your event tracking.”

Would anyone know how to solve this, when using flutter ?

If it is possible to use this tool in flutter web site

Comment: any solution for this problem??

Comment: Hi, did you solve this issue?